# Jquery validator form submitted even if invalid

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

I have a simple search form using HTML, PHP, and jQuery but the form submits even though some fields are empty and the validator warnings appear for a moment. So I would submit the form, the warnings about "Required field" appear, and it submits anyway. The validator is being triggered but isn't stopping the form.

HTML + PHP

```
<form action="dater.php" method="post" id="daterange">
<table width = "1000px">
<col width="250px" />
<col width="250px" />
<col width="250px" />
<col width="250px" />
<tr>
<? dateRangeView(); ?>
<td><input class="comment" type="text" name="groups" id="groupname"  placeholder="Enter group name"> *</td>
<td><input class="comment" type="text" name="employee" id="staffname" placeholder="Enter employee name"> *</td>
</tr></table>

*Leave these blank to view all<br>
<button class="mainButton" id="viewTimesheets" value="viewTimesheets" type="submit">View</button>

function dateRangeView() 
{

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT weekending FROM payroll_ts ORDER BY weeke DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo'<td><select id="startdate" class="infotable" name="startdate"><option value="">---- Start date ----</option>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo'<option value="'.$row{'weeke'}.'">'.$row{'weeke'}.'</option>';
}
echo'</select><br><td><select id="enddate" class="infotable" name="enddate"> <option value="">---- End date ----</option>';

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT weekending FROM payroll_ts ORDER BY weeke DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo'<option value="'.$row{'weeke'}.'">'.$row{'weeke'}.'</option>';
}

echo'</select><br></td>';

}
```

VALIDATOR PLUGIN CODE

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

/*-------------Validator-------------*/

$.validator.setDefaults({
submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); 
form.submit();}
});

$(function() {

$("#daterange").validate({
rules: {
startdate: "required",
enddate: "required"
},
messages: {
startdate: "required",
enddate: "required"
}
});
});

</script>
```

I've been at it for four hours now, used .on(), return false; onSubmit() and e.preventDefault(); although I may have gotten the syntax on those messed up... This is the plugin I'm using... http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: You may have a JavaScript error somewhere that stops the JavaScript execution and the form submits anyway. Does your console show any errors?

Comment: This is not the cause of your problem but you don't need the `submitHandler` callback function at all, unless you want to over-ride the default action of the `form`, like if you use `ajax` for example.

Comment: It's definetely the PHP, I've run the exact same code on multiple static forms now without difficulty, even with selectors. Any PHP gurus care to help? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert('submitted'); 
            form.submit();
        }
    });

    $('#daterange').validate({ 
        rules: {
            startdate: {
                required: true
            },
            enddate: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Working JsFiddle example **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kXWnV/)**

Hope this helps, Thank you

or here is the code for you both works

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.validator.setDefaults({
submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); 
 form.submit();}
});

$(function() {

$("#daterange").validate({
rules: {
startdate: "required",
enddate: "required"
},
messages: {
startdate: "required",
enddate: "required"
}
});
});

});
```

Comment: Same thing happens, it must be something to do with the PHP, the code works on static forms. .on() should catch dynamic problems though...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#daterange").validate({
    rules: {
    startdate: "required",
    enddate: "required"
    },
    messages: {
    startdate: "required",
    enddate: "required"
    }
   });

if($("#daterange").valid()) {
    // call your function;
    alert("submitted!");
}
```

});